# Pingdom breaks IIS output caching when using varyByHeaders (Cookie)

Tags: iis, outputcache, pingdom

I've been doing a lot of research on output caching lately and have been able to successfully implement output caching in IIS via web.config with either `varyByQueryString` or `varyByHeaders`.

However, then there's the issue of Pingdom's Performance & Real User Monitoring (or PRUM). They have a "fun" little `beforeUnload` routine that sets a `PRUM_EPISODES` cookie just as you navigate away from the page so it can time your next page load. The value of this cookie is basically a `unixtimestamp()` which changes every second.

As you can image, this completely breaks **user-mode output caching** because now every request will be sent with a different `Cookie` header on each subsequent request.

So two questions:

1. My first inclination says to find a way to drop `PRUM_EPISODES` cookie before it reaches the server since it's serves no purpose to the actual application (this is also my informal request for a `ClientOnly` flag in the next HTTP version). Is anyone familiar with a technique for dropping individual cookies before they reach IIS' output caching engine or some other technique to leverage `varyByHeaders="Cookie"` while ignoring `PRUM_EPISODES`? Haven't found such a technique for `Web.config` as of yet.
2. Do all monitoring systems manipulate cookies in this manner (changing every page request) for their tracking mechanisms and do they not realize that by doing so, they break user-mode output caching?

Comment: While I'm not at all familiar with IIS, I question how you're wanting to use Pingdom.  Do you really want to send a cached response?  I would think that you want your server to actually do a little bit of something when the Pingdom request comes in to validate the health of your service.  I've always used a small routine that pings the database and checks available memory before returning a good response.  Of course, your system will be different but I never wanted to cache the health information.

Comment: Kind of moot point now; we've opted to just remove it for now. But it was definitely what was preventing IIS from caching pages.

Comment: Have an open ticket with Pingdom. They're going to look more into the issue, but indicated this is the first time they've heard of this side effect.

Comment: Just a quick update: Pingdom replied with "will not fix" for the time being.